# Open form to create new record for different entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom ribbon button that I have added to one of my entities. From that button I want to have the user click it and CRM take them to the form to create a new record for a different, custom, entity type.

I have tried opening the url of a record by passing in the entity name in place of the code (as this can change across organisations) but it threw an error when I tested it. My guess is that I need to pass through some kind of parameter to say that the form is to be a "create" type form.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Entity Type Code (etc) will always be the same for every organisation into which you import the same solution. While GUIDs for individual records created in each will be different, the etc would be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [openEntityForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenEntityForm), see this example:

```js
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("account", null, parameters);
```

Comment: Worth noting this requires rollup 8 to use

Comment: Ups... So you can update to rollup 8 :D check this [article](http://dynamicslollipops.blogspot.pt/2012/06/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-create-new.html) have one example with url, thats works before UR8

Comment: +1 for something new to me. And the link. And me feeling bad for you for the downvote on the other post. :)

Comment: Is it a default method in CRM and is it supported? How can I close the the form from my JS afterwrds?